# Looping script to extract specific data from text file

Tags: python, loops

I am looking to use Python to loop through a file and pull data from two specific data columns, the example data is below.

```
----------------------------------
Local Cell ID  Cell Name                        Physical cell ID  Additional spectrum emission  Cell active state  Cell admin state  Cell middle block timer(min)  Cell FDD TDD indication  Subframe assignment  Special subframe patterns  

11             12345678912345678912345678912    427               1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
12             12345678912345678912345678912    130               1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
14             12345678912345678912345678912    94                1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
15             12345678912345678912345678912    37                1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
21             12345678912345678912345678912    188               1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
22             12345678912345678912345678912    203               1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
24             12345678912345678912345678912    209               1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
25             12345678912345678912345678912    230               1                             Active             Unblock           NULL                          TDD                      SA2                  SSP6                       
(Number of results = 8)


---    END
```

I have used the below script to pull each line with a certain value but I am wondering if it would be possible to just pull the data under "Cell Name" and "Physical Cell ID" which for line 4 would be 12345678912345678912345678912 and 427.

```
signal = open('signal.txt', 'r') 
newFile = open('results2.txt', 'w') 
for line in signal: 
    if 'False' in line: 
        print('.', end="") 
        newFile.write(line) 
    else: 
        print(" ", end="") 
newFile.close() 
signal.close() 
print('Done')
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function

Comment: you can also use `pandas` `read_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

@J.Byrne, another method, would be to use the `pandas` dataframe `read_csv` to pull the data in (ignore row 1 and bottom data, add the column names) and the choose the columns that you are interested in.

see this code to pull:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('signal.txt', skiprows=2,skipfooter=4, sep='\s+', 
            names=[
                'Local Cell ID',  
                'Cell Name',                        
                'Physical cell ID',  
                'Additional spectrum emission',  
                'Cell active state',  
                'Cell admin state',  
                'Cell middle block timer(min)',  
                'Cell FDD TDD indication',  
                'Subframe assignment',  
                'Special subframe patterns'], 
            engine='python')

df
```

Result here:

```
Local Cell ID   Cell Name   Physical cell ID    Additional spectrum emission    Cell active state   Cell admin state    Cell middle block timer(min)    Cell FDD TDD indication Subframe assignment Special subframe patterns
0   11  12345678912345678912345678912   427 1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
1   12  12345678912345678912345678912   130 1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
2   14  12345678912345678912345678912   94  1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
3   15  12345678912345678912345678912   37  1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
4   21  12345678912345678912345678912   188 1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
5   22  12345678912345678912345678912   203 1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
6   24  12345678912345678912345678912   209 1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
7   25  12345678912345678912345678912   230 1   Active  Unblock NaN TDD SA2 SSP6
```

Use this to filter:

```
df[["Cell Name","Physical cell ID"]]
```

Result here:

```
Cell Name   Physical cell ID
0   12345678912345678912345678912   427
1   12345678912345678912345678912   130
2   12345678912345678912345678912   94
3   12345678912345678912345678912   37
4   12345678912345678912345678912   188
5   12345678912345678912345678912   203
6   12345678912345678912345678912   209
7   12345678912345678912345678912   230
```

Comment: Thanks @Medwin, I have used your script and it is pulling correctly, I have now attempted to the same data but with more column (61 in total) but I am getting the below error:

pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 61 fields in line 11, saw 205. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: it is possible the file has a row that spits out 205 columns. It is hard to know which line until you go through the file. change the `read_csv` to `df=pd.read_csv('signal.txt', skiprows=2,skipfooter=4, sep='\s+', 
            names=['patterns'], 
            engine='python',
            lineterminator='\n')`. I have added  `lineterminator='\n'`.

Comment: also try this: `df=pd.read_csv('signal.txt', skiprows=2,skipfooter=4, sep='\s+', names=['patterns'], engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)`; this tries to ignore the `bad lines`.

Comment: Still the same error with both of the above, see the data I require is only "Cell Name" and "Physical Cell ID", would it be possible to first clear any data after column 'Special subframe patterns'? Then I could run the initial script on the remaining data.

Comment: I am not sure that will work. But i think another way will be to trace what line in the `signal.txt` is causing that problem and create a case logic to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks Medwin, I will add columns one at a time to find the one causing the issue.

Comment: I though about another logic, using regular expression. I will post it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

see another method below. You can loop through the lines in the txt file `signal.txt` and then call the search function to get the `CellName` or `PhysicalCellID`.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
mydicts = []

def FindCellName(line):#create a function looking at each line
    CellName=None #empty the variable
    j=re.findall('\d{29}', line) #find string with 29 characters
    if len(j)>0:
            CellName=j[0] #if it exists assign it to CellName
    return CellName

def FindPhysicalCellID(line):#create a function looking at each line
    PhysicalCellID=None #empty the variable
    res= re.search('\d{29}(.*)               1', line) #find string after the 29 characters and before the 1
    if res:
            PhysicalCellID=res.group(1) #if it exists assign it to PhysicalCellID
    return PhysicalCellID

with open('signal.txt') as topo_file:
    for line in topo_file:
        if FindCellName(line) : #if CellName exists 
            mydicts.append((FindCellName(line), FindPhysicalCellID(line))) # append CellName and PhysicalCellID in the diction
    df=pd.DataFrame(mydicts, columns=('CellName', 'PhysicalCellID'))
df
```

result below:

```
CellName    PhysicalCellID
0   12345678912345678912345678912   427
1   12345678912345678912345678912   130
2   12345678912345678912345678912   94
3   12345678912345678912345678912   37
4   12345678912345678912345678912   188
5   12345678912345678912345678912   203
6   12345678912345678912345678912   209
7   12345678912345678912345678912   230
​
```